# VisualForce False Duplicate Content On Moz Report

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, website-integration

We are using Salesforce's Visualforce to run one of our websites.

We use Moz to monitor SEO issues.

Moz has identified more issues pages than we have - see the attached image. We have only a few thousand pages at best. However Google and Moz are taking keywords and adding it to the end of the domain and creating a URL that doesn't exist. Recently I made all of these URLs redirect to the home page to see if it resolved the issue - it didn't and the URLs that don't exist are still being crawled.

What do I do - this is effecting my rank. Please help?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've seen similar issues before. There are a few ways you can tackle this

A) Add a robots.txt file where you can specify which all pages/ prefixes you want to disallow for crawling.

See [this](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=sites_creating_and_editing_sites.htm&siteLang=en_US) link for more details.

e.g.

> A file that determines which parts of your public site Web spiders and
>   other Web robots can access. Web robots are often used by search
>   engines to categorize and archive websites. HTML tags are not allowed,
>   as they are not compatible with robots.txt spiders. For Visualforce
>   pages, add `contentType="text/plain"` to the `<apex:page>` tag.

Example disallowing all robots from indexing all pages:

```
<apex:page contentType="text/plain">
    User-agent: *  # Applies to all robots
    Disallow: /    # Disallow indexing of all pages
    </apex:page>
```

> Example allowing all robots to index all pages:

```
<apex:page contentType="text/plain">
            User-agent: *  # Applies to all robots
            Disallow:      # Allow indexing of all pages
            </apex:page>
```

B) Make sure your `sitemap` includes only the URLs for the pages that you want the crawlers to index. Refer to [this](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/creating-a-sitemap-file) link for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance - but does this mean I will have to disallow access to all the URLs that shouldn't be crawled because that is a huge list. I've tried updating the sitemap but it is not helping.

Comment: No, you can use wildcards to create your robots.txt file to specifically exclude the URLs that you do want to exclude from crawling